# Old VB6 DHTML Porting to HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3 (Vue, Angular or React)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, com, vb6, vue.js

I have a VB6 client server solution.

**Client side:** DHTML ActiveX control that runs in IE. It has approx. 123 Dialogs + HTML/DSR files. It also use 13 Helper classes in a separate client side DLL. At client side, we also have around 250 Crystal Report files which a separate .NET executable loads and display. We install all client side by giving our clients a setup MSI file.

**Server Side:** We have 4 ASP pages that client side ActiveX control calls to login and send compressed data. These ASP pages call 25 COM DLLs to perform SQL Server database operations.

Now we want following changes:

**New Client side** to pure HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3. We have plans to use VueJS over AngularJS (as it is TypeScript based) or ReactJS (as it has JXS). We want a simple AMD, two way binding and templating framework and VueJS seems to provide all these.

**New Server Side** to Web API by wrapping Classic ASP + 25+ COM DLLs in ASP.NET Web API.

Now my questions is:

1. Is there a code conversion tool available for VB6 to JavaScript?  Is
2. VueJS is the right choice for client side framework? Are there any
3. known issues for wrapping COM DLLs to Web API and then calling them
   via Ajax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm afraid that recommendation questions are off-topic for SO, and the question is too broad for the SO format as well. These help topics can help with what's on-topic and scoped: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think you should make these 3 separate questions